# Number of strings of length 10 consisting of the digits 0,1,2,3 with even sum of digits

Tags: combinatorics

> A weight for string is simply the sum of digits. Now if the digits are 0, 1, 2 and 3, how many possible strings are there of even weight if the string is 10 digits?

My reasoning: there must be an even number of odd digits, so select $2i$ positions out of ten and the remaining $10-2i$ digits are either zero or two. Summing over all possibilities we get

$$\sum_{i=1}^{5}2^{10-2i}\binom{10}{2i}$$

But the answer is:

$$2^{10}\sum_{i=1}^{5}\binom{10}{2i}$$

What do I do?

Comment: your sum should start at $i=0$

Answer (score 5):

To count even weight strings, you can choose the first $9$ digits arbitrarily ($4^9$ ways to do this); and then you will have two choices for the last digit so as to make the sum even.

So half the strings have even weight.

Comment: The only characters available are $1,2,3,4$

Comment: but that's a good argument

Comment: @ModdedBear: Thanks!  BTW, I think my answer takes into account that there are four choices for each digit--though I think the choices are $0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. What is wrong with me today?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have selected which are the positions occupying odd digits doesn't mean you know which number each of the odd numbers is, to do this you have $2$ choices for each digit.

So you have to multiply by $2^{2i}$. Clearly $2^{10-2i}2^{2i}=2^{10}$

So the answer is $2^{10}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{2i}$.

This is equal to $2^{10}$ multiplied by the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3\dots 10\}$ with an even number of elements, it is known that this is exactly half of all the subsets.

Thus the answer is $2^{10}\times 2^9=2^{19}$ which is indeed half of $2^{20}=4^{10}$